# Converting from arabic string to hex html string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, hex

I need to convert arabic characters to its hex code as in character map, for example
in windows 7 character map with font "Arabic Typesetting" and character set "DOS:Arabic"  when choose char 'ب' it gives U+0628 (0xA0) I need to get this with C#(in more details mvc3 razor view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you need to take each character, get its integral value, then format it as a string using the [hexadecimal format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString).

For example:

```
string name = "أحمد";
foreach (char c in name)
{
    int value = (int)c;
    string hex = value.ToString("X4");
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", hex, c);
}
```

You might also find this helpful: [How to: Convert Between Hexadecimal Strings and Numeric Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx).